# Payment Gateway partial payments

Tags: payment-gateway

My question is simple.

With my auto-capture off, if I make authentication for $20, can I make a capture of amount greater than $20 from it??

I can obviously capture $20 from it. If I cannot capture the amount greater than $20, then what is the procedure/flow to make that happen?

Comment: No, you cannot capture more then you authorize

Comment: Yes. So far I was also on this conclusion but my colleague had confused me, so I asked it here. Thanks for your response, I appreciate it.